# Has the "partial Sophomore's Dream function" been studied before?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request

We can consider the generalized Harmonic numbers $$H_{n,m} := \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^{m}} $$ as a partial version of the Riemann zeta function, because $$\lim_{n \to \infty} H_{n,m} = \zeta(m). $$

We could also define the "partial Sophomore's Dream function" $$S_{r} := \sum_{q=1}^{r}\frac{1}{q^{q}} ,$$
as we have $$\lim_{r \to \infty} S_{r} := S= \int_{0}^{1}x^{-x}dx ,$$ where the integral on the right is equal to the first Sophomore's Dream constant.

> **Question**: while studying the series $$\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}(S-S_{r}) \approx 0.3371877158, $$ I was wondering whether the function $S_{r}$ has already been studied, and if someone has coined a name for it that is hopefully less awkward than mine.

Comment: Not exactly your concern, but not far : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/34977341/Sophomore-s-Dream-Function .

Comment: @JJacquelin Yes, I've seen your paper before! But indeed this question is about a slightly different topic

Comment: crossposted at https://mathoverflow.net/q/416145/11260